# Android - Permission to use Camera and Write to External Storage

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I am trying to ask for permission to use the Camera and Writing to External Storage.
My Main Activity is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                {
                    if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA});
                    }
                }

                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_PERM_WRITE_STORAGE);

            }
                else
                {
                    takePhoto(); // calls this method
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I have included in my Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I get this error:

```
 cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(MainActivity,String[])
cannot find symbol method checkSelfPermission(Context,String)
```

What is it that I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Make sure your compileSdkVersion is 23 or higher.

Comment: Check that you are using ActivityCompat.

Comment: I am using compileSdkVersion 27

Comment: I am using ActivityCompat as well.

Comment: Which version of the support library are you using? You need at least 24.1.0. Also, `requestPermissions` takes 3 arguments, not 2.

Comment: Changing the support library to 24.1.0 did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the request camera part try this

`final int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;`

`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},RequestCameraPermissionID);`

Comment: This gives an error saying cannot resolve symbol method getActivity() and cannot resolve symbol method RequestCameraPermissionID